# Обращение к модели laravel 8 из вебсокета

Tags: php, laravel-8

как решить эту проблему? отправляю сообщение из JS-вебсокета -> сообщение попадает в серверный вебсокет -> обращаюсь к контроллеру -> контроллер обращается к модели (для примера Offer::all()). Выходит эта ошибка:

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /home/aladser/projects/offer-tracker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1653
Stack trace:**

Если обращаться не через модель, а фасад DB ( например, DB:table(...) ), то выходит ошибка серверного вебсокета

**A facade root has not been set.**